# NodeJs: Await inside mssql 'done' emitter

Tags: javascript, sql, syntax, async-await

I am using the 'mssql' package to process a sql query, calling an async function when the 'row' emitter fires.

When the 'done' emitter fires, I want to wait for all tasks to complete... this is where i am having a problem.

EXAMPLE:

```
const sql = require('mssql')
let tasks = [];

sql.connect(config, err => {

    const request = new sql.Request()
    request.stream = true;
    request.query('select * from theTable') 

    request.on('row', row => {
        task.push( callAsyncFunction(row) );
    })

    request.on('error', err => {
        // Do something
    })

    request.on('done', result => {
        await Promise.all(tasks);
        //THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS: 
        //SyntaxError: await is only valid in 
        // async function 

    })
})

sql.on('error', err => {
    // handle error
})
```

Can anyone help with my syntax here?
Thank you!

Comment: Make it async, eg `async (result) => {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try making anonymous function `async`
you can make anonymous  functions `async` too

```js
request.on('done', async(result) => {
        await Promise.all(tasks);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate the anonymous function with `async`:

```js
const sql = require('mssql')
let tasks = [];

sql.connect(config, err => {

    const request = new sql.Request()
    request.stream = true;
    request.query('select * from theTable') 

    request.on('row', row => {
        task.push( callAsyncFunction(row) );
    })

    request.on('error', err => {
        // Do something
    })

    request.on('done', async (result) => {
        await Promise.all(tasks);
        //THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS: 
        //SyntaxError: await is only valid in 
        // async function 

    })
})

sql.on('error', err => {
    // handle error
})
```